# c# get property with specific attribute from list objects

Tags: c#, linq, list, reflection, attributes

Having List of objects:

```
List<ConfigurationObjectBase> ObjectRegistry;
```

Having below Attribute and some of the above objects' decorated with that Attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = true)]
public sealed class PropertyCanHaveReference : Attribute
{
    public PropertyCanHaveReference(Type valueType)
    {
        this.ValueType = valueType;
    }

    public Type ValueType { get; set; }
}
```

Now, I want to find all objects whose property is decorated with that Attribute.

Trying below code, seems I am doing wrong:

```
List<ConfigurationObjectBase> tmplist = ObjectRegistry.Where(o => (o.GetType().GetProperties().Where(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PropertyCanHaveReference), true).Length > 0)));
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Shouldn't the second `Where` be `Any`?

Comment: At first glance your code seems right (although you might want to stick with conventions and call the attribute class `PropertyCanHaveReferenceAttribute`). What is actually going "wrong"? Do you get error messages or no results where you'd expect some? Please provide example objects that don't work or an [minimal, complete and verfiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

It seems you have some syntax errors in the code line you show. And you can convert some `Where`/`Count` combinations to `Any()`. This works for me:

```
List<ConfigurationObjectBase> tmplist = 
       ObjectRegistry.Where(o => o.GetType().GetProperties().Any(p =>
              p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PropertyCanHaveReference), true).Any())).ToList();
```

So you filter for all objects that have *any* property that has *any* attribute of your type.

You can also use the generic `GetCustomAttribute<T>()` method:

```
List<ConfigurationObjectBase> tmplist =
       ObjectRegistry.Where(o => o.GetType().GetProperties().Any(p =>
                  p.GetCustomAttribute<PropertyCanHaveReference>(true) != null)).ToList();
```

---

Please consider to name your attribute class according to conventions `PropertyCanHaveReferenceAttribute`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code to get the list of object, which has it's properties decorated  with custom attribute:

```
        List<ConfigurationObjectBase> tmplist = ObjectRegistry.Where(o =>   
          (o.GetType().GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | 
                                   System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic | 
           System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).Where(
            prop => Attribute.IsDefined(prop, typeof(PropertyCanHaveReference)))).Any()).ToList();
```

Your code would get only public properties, which has been decorated. Code above will get both: public and non-public.

Answer (score 0):

This System.Type extension method should work:

```
public static IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> GetPropertiesWithAttribute<TAttribute>(this Type type) where TAttribute : Attribute
{
    var properties = type.GetProperties();
    // Find all attributes of type TAttribute for all of the properties belonging to the type.
    foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
    {
        var attributes = property.GetCustomAttributes(true).Where(a => a.GetType() == typeof(TAttribute)).ToList();
        if (attributes != null && attributes.Any())
        {
            yield return property;
        }
    }
}
```